# Cannot read/write FTP directory vsftpd on centos 6.0 (empty folder)

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, directory, home-directory, vsftpd

I have Centos 6.0 and installed vsftp with YUM, I added a user with Webmin panel, set its home dir to "/var/www/html" and its shell to "/bin/sh", user id is 500, user group is same as name: "adrian_ftp".

When I start a ftp program it logs in but the remote folder always shows empty.
I set directory owner and group to adrian_ftp:adrian_ftp , no change, I also made them 0777, no change.

Any ideas? I tried for over 3-4 hours :|

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? .. "getenforce"

Comment: it says `Enforcing`

Comment: Restart httpd, then try your ftp user, try to list a directory, then run "ausearch -ts recent -m avc" and provide the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's selinux for 99 % ;-)

```
# getenforce
Enforcing
```

Turn it off by:

```
# setenforce 0
# vim /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

And set it to "disabled" in that file or "permissive" if you plan to turn it on sometime in future or you want to track selinux errors.

For FTP I highly recommend NOT to turn it off. Follow the [RHEL 6 guides](http://docs.redhat.com) how to set it up properly for a FTP site.

Comment: can you give me more info please? It says `Enforcing` , httpd won't start after I set `setenforce` to 0/1

Comment: It was* the selinux that is messing the FTP, I lost too many hours with it already so I just disabled it. I see it is also disabled on other servers.

Comment: Disabled selinux and set in vsftpd.conf this: `chroot_local_user=YES` to keep user in its own directory.

Comment: So you succeeded, that's good. I still recommend to run FTP in the selinux mode. You will need to tag directories for selinux - see any selinux guide (RHEL 6 documentation is the best source).